# Visual Studio showing 403 error when trying to check in large file to ADO Services (TFVC not GIT)

Tags: azure-devops, tfvc

When trying to check in a large file (about 27 MB) to our ADO services instance (https://<our_instance>.visualstudio.com/) I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error.  Checking in smaller files is OK. Only receive this with large files so there shouldn't be any access issues.  Also, when trying this from the web it says an IDE is required to check in a file of that size.  Using Visual Studio 2022.

From what I am seeing this file size should be supported and no problem checking in but when I try, I receive this message.

```
D:\<path to file\<file.ext>: Please contact your administrator.  There was an error contacting the server.
Technical information (for administrator):
  HTTP code 403: Forbidden
```

I'm not able to find any way to get more detailed information or find any solution online so hoping someone here has some insight to why this is happening and how to remedy this.

Has anyone run into this before and know how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure what the default limits are set by Azure but i bet there is a config somewhere that will let you send more data before cutting off.   Either a rate limit or maybe even a timeout setting is something to consider.   But 403 being Forbidden means it wanted to work but broke some criteria, so check your settings.